# bash script run forever in the background and stop messages

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
php wes.php &
sleep 10
php wes1.php &
sleep 10
php wes2.php &
sleep 10
php wes3.php &
sleep 10
php wes4.php &
sleep 10
php wes5.php &
```

However I keep receiving messages from the script so I want to keep the scripts working in the background but also stop the alerts/messages that result from executing .

Comment: Btw: what did you mean with forever? In case you want to survive the terminal session, you should start your script with nohup (or a similar terminal session providing that functionality, e.g. screen)

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect output and errors to `/dev/null`.

```
php wes.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: unfortunately it forces the shell script to execute the program consecutive(executes the 2nd program after 1st finish ) instead after 10 seconds as specified .

Comment: @Michael : You mean that it doesn't sleep for 10 seconds before running 2nd program? [This](http://www.ideone.com/jSdjL) program opens a firefox window, sleeps for 3 seconds and then opens a gnome-terminal. Isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I miss the simplest solution here: use `nohup yourscript.sh &`

`nohup` will make sure, that there are no handlers to the terminal are left open.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output somewhere:

```
php wes.php > somewhere.txt &
```

Comment: I don't want to store the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

Comment: Consider directing new users to `tmux` instead of `screen`. It's way better behaved, easier to configure, has all the features of screen and a few more, and the project is actively maintained.

Comment: can you please elaborate the screen method ... I don't get how it will be useful in the bash script

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in '' 1 2 3 4 5
do
    php wes$i.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    sleep 10
done
```